# Using context with cancel, Go routine doesn't terminate

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, go-context

I'm new to Go and concurrency in Go. I'm trying to use a Go context to cancel a set of Go routines once I find a member with a given ID.

A Group stores a list of Clients, and each Client has a list of Members. I want to search in parallel all the Clients and all their Members to find a Member with a given ID. Once this Member is found, I want to cancel all the other Go routines and return the discovered Member.

I've tried the following implementation, using a context.WithCancel and a WaitGroup.

This doesn't work however, and hangs indefinitely, never getting past the line waitGroup.Wait(), but I'm not sure why exactly.

```
func (group *Group) MemberWithID(ID string) (*models.Member, error) {
    found := make(chan *models.Member)
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    for _, client := range group.Clients {
        waitGroup.Add(1)

        go func(clientToQuery Client) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()

            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            default:
            }

            member, _ := client.ClientMemberWithID(ID)
            if member != nil {
                found <- member
                cancel()
                return
            }

        } (client)

    }

    waitGroup.Wait()

    if len(found) > 0 {
        return <-found, nil
    }

    return nil, fmt.Errorf("no member found with given id")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`found` is an unbuffered channel, so sending on it blocks until there is someone ready to receive from it.

Your `main()` function would be the one to receive from it, but only after `waitGroup.Wait()` returns. But that will block until all launched goroutines call `waitGroup.Done()`. But that won't happen until they return, which won't happen until they can send on `found`. It's a deadlock.

If you change `found` to be buffered, that will allow sending values on it even if `main()` is not ready to receive from it (as many values as big the buffer is).

But you should receive from `found` before `waitGroup.Wait()` returns.

Another solution is to use a buffer of 1 for `found`, and use non-blocking send on `found`. That way the first (fastest) goroutine will be able to send the result, and the rest (given we're using non-blocking send) will simply skip sending.

Also note that it should be the `main()` that calls `cancel()`, not each launched goroutines individually.

Comment: Oh I see, how would I know to call cancel from main though when a member is found?

Comment: In this case I wouldn't even use `Context`: you don't really use it. `client.ClientMemberWithID` doesn't use it, so it's rather useless here and only complicates things. It would be useful if you'd pass / use it when executing the database query.

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of use case I think a `sync.Once` is probably a better fit than a channel. When you find the first non-nil member, you want to do two different things:

1. Record the member you found.
2. Cancel the remaining goroutines.

A buffered channel can easily do (1), but makes (2) a bit more complicated. But a `sync.Once` is perfect for doing two different things the first time something interesting happens!

---

I would also suggest aggregating non-trivial errors, so that you can report something more useful than `no member found` if, say, your database connection fails or some other nontrivial error occurs. You can use a `sync.Once` for that, too!

---

Putting it all together, I would want to see something like this (https://play.golang.org/p/QZXUUnbxOv5):

```golang
func (group *Group) MemberWithID(ctx context.Context, id string) (*Member, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    var (
        wg sync.WaitGroup

        member    *Member
        foundOnce sync.Once

        firstNontrivialErr error
        errOnce            sync.Once
    )

    for _, client := range group.Clients {
        wg.Add(1)
        client := client // https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            m, err := client.ClientMemberWithID(ctx, id)
            if m != nil {
                foundOnce.Do(func() {
                    member = m
                    cancel()
                })
            } else if nf := (*MemberNotFoundError)(nil); !errors.As(err, &nf) {
                errOnce.Do(func() {
                    firstNontrivialErr = err
                })
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()

    if member == nil {
        if firstNontrivialErr != nil {
            return nil, firstNontrivialErr
        }
        return nil, &MemberNotFoundError{ID: id}
    }
    return member, nil
}
```

Comment: The equivalent using buffered channels instead of `sync.Once` (https://play.golang.org/p/blsYV_eMgN_X) also works, but seems a bit more verbose to me.

Comment: thank you so much for this solution, sync.Once seems really useful I hadn't heard of that before